# Responsive Full Width Slideshow with maximum page height

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I have a slideshow ( images ) that is currently 100% of the browser and stacked on other page sections. The problem is when on a large screen ( imac 27 and bigger ) the image expands beyond the fold.

It's okay if it get's smaller and goes above the fold but not below. Here is my current attempt.

This a Wordpress theme built using Bootstrap CDN.I am also using the [amazing slick slider.](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Essentially I'm trying to make the images stretch the size of the browser window and not any bigger ( bleeding down to a scroll )

***HTML:***

```
<div class="page-section">
    <div class="slider slick">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
        <div class="casestudy-slide" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );">
            <div class="casestudy-slide-text">
                View Our Case Studies
            </div>
            <div class="casestudy-logos">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/casestudy-logos.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page-section">
    other page content
</div>
<div class="page-section">
    other page content
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.page-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.casestudy-slide {
    display: block;
    margin-top:-200%;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-bottom:47%;
    margin:0 !important;
    height: auto;
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
   -moz-background-size: cover!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
   -o-background-size: cover!important; 
}
```

Please [check out the page here](http://2016.times10.net/work/) and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Jeesus your page is heavy! It's still loading (over 170MB!) You have images over 15MB! Anything above 150KB is considered big. I have 50/50 connection, and it's still loading. You have bigger issues than the slider imo...

Comment: @dingo_d thanks I compressed a bunch of them and re-sized as well.

Comment: It's still 8MB, but that's way better than >170MB :D About the slide issue, try using viewport units to make images stretch.